# Переместить или скопировать элемент jquery

Tags: jquery

UPD: Вот такая конструкция работает, но получается выбрать не конкретный элемент, после которого нужно поставить блок, а все элементы класса item.

```
$('.item').eq(14).insertBefore($('.item'))
```

А в данном примере мне нужно вставить только 14 элемент после другого элемента (в примере он тоже 14), но так ничего не происходит: `$('.item').eq(14).insertBefore($('.item').eq(14))`

---

Привет! Не понимаю почему не работает функция .append() в jquery. Если я выбираю элемент и внутри append прописываю текст (string), то он работает как и должен. Код для примера:

```
$('.myclass').append("<div class='otherDIV'>something</div>");
```

А если я выбираю элемент, который я хочу вставить с помощью jquery, вставка не происходит:

```
$('.myclass').append($('.otherDIV'));
```

Пробовал использовать appendTo, insertAfter - тоже не срабатывают. Подскажите, в чем я не прав и как все-таки можно выбрать элемент и вставить его в нужное место с помощью jquery.

Возможно нужно обрисовать общую картину: я пытаюсь перемещать объекты в сетке. Перемещать не в пространстве страницы, а в разметке, т.е. поставить после нужного мне . Посмотреть сетку можно на этом [image: скриншоте].

Код перемещения объектов:

```
// Проверяю, есть ли до (сзади) текущего широкого поста
//  высокий пост. Если есть, и если после него есть пустой блок,
//  я ставлю широкий пост после пустого блока, а до него (пустого
//  ставлю первый попавшийся квадратный пост из последующих

if($('.item').eq(i-1).attr('sise') == 'vertical') {
  if ($('.item').eq(i+1).hasClass('ADDED')) {

    console.log('широкий стоит после высокого');

    // начинаю перебор всех блоков после текущего
    for (let a=(i); a < $('.item').length; a++) {
      console.log('перебор начался');
      if (($('.item').eq(a).hasClass('ADDED')==false) && ($('.item').eq(a).attr('sise') == '')) {
        //ставлю перед (до) этим (широким) блоком обычный квадратный
        $('.item').eq(i).before($('.item').eq(a)); a++; i++;
        //удаляю квадратный
        $('.item').eq(a).remove();
        //ставлю текущий блок после пустого
        $('.item').eq(i).after($('.item').eq(i+1))
        //удаляю текущий блок
        $('.item').eq(i).remove();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Код сетки:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="vertical" class="item">{{> post/post-tall}}</div>
  <!-- square -->
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="vertical" class="item">{{> post/post-tall}}</div>
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post-double}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="vertical" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
  <div sise="wide" class="item">{{> post/post}}</div>
</div>
```

Надеюсь, понятно изложил

Comment: Гляньте плагин [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/), там все есть, в том числе и перемещения по разным позициям и сторонам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где в Вашем коде неработающий `append`?

```js
function move() {
  if ($(".one .child").length == 2)
    $(".parent").eq(1).append($(".child").eq(1));
  else
    $(".parent").eq(0).append($(".child").eq(1));
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  display: block;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent one">
  <span class="child">1</span>
  <span class="child">2</span>
</div>
<div class="parent two"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="move()">Move</button>
```